# Dynamically changing list view t in android

Tags: android

In my app I get few details in the realtime and I want to show them  in LIstview with onclick listener.  I know how to just put the list view but I dont know how to provide a Oncliklister  for dynamically chagning view .

Can any one provide  a some insight on the same ..

Comment: Your question is a bit vague... What do you want to display when onClick() is called? You could create a class that extends BaseAdapter, then you could control which views get displayed when. If you want to change the list dynamically, you can make use of notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView has a setOnItemClickListener() method that will let you set a listener to get callbacks whenever an item in the list is clicked on.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
      Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
      //Do what you want with the listItem
   } 
});
```